# Add foreign key on UpgradeSchema return "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"?

Tags: magento2, upgradeschema

I want to add a new attribute to `catalog_product_website` table named `id_admin_user` to make relation with `admin_user` table.

PS: I want to do that to save the ID of the admin user who added a product.

So, I create an `UpgradeSchema` with this code

```
$setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $setup->getTable('catalog_product_website'),
    'id_admin_user',
    [
        'type' => Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        'size' => null,
        'nullable' => false,
        'comment' => 'ID ADMIN USER'
    ]
);
$setup->getConnection()->addForeignKey(
    $setup->getFkName(
        'catalog_product_website',
        'id_admin_user',
        'admin_user',
        'user_id'
    ),
    $setup->getTable('catalog_product_website'),
    'id_admin_user',

    $setup->getTable('admin_user'),
    'user_id',
    Table::ACTION_CASCADE
);
```

But when I execute the `setup:upgrade` I get this error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `magento_test`.`#sql-357_165b` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, setup should $setup. Check following code:

```
$setup->getConnection()->addForeignKey(
    $setup->getFkName(
        'catalog_product_website',
        'id_admin_user',
        'admin_user',
        'user_id'
    ),
    $setup->getTable('catalog_product_website'),
    'id_admin_user',

    $installer->getTable('admin_user'),
    'user_id',
    Table::ACTION_CASCADE
);
```

**[Update]**

Try following way:

```
$setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $setup->getTable('catalog_product_website'),
    'id_admin_user',
    [
        'type' => Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        'size' => null,
        'nullable' => false,
        'unsigned' => true,
        'comment' => 'ID ADMIN USER'
    ]
);
$setup->getConnection()->addForeignKey(
    $setup->getFkName(
        'catalog_product_website',
        'id_admin_user',
        'admin_user',
        'user_id'
    ),
    $setup->getTable('catalog_product_website'),
    'id_admin_user',

    $setup->getTable('admin_user'),
    'user_id',
    Table::ACTION_CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Still getting the same error sir ( I replace `$installer` with `$setup` )

Comment: Check updated answer, working fine with 2.3.

Comment: It's work sir, thanks a lot for your help, I think the problem was on the column configuration

Comment: Sir, do you advise me to use this method, Or adding a new attribute using EAV ?

Comment: For EAV use, upgrade data, not schema

Comment: to know what I want to do, I created a new `admin_user` role with some resources, this role can add products, so I want to save the `ID` of `admin_user` on each product save, to filter them and give him just the list of his products. for that is this method `(add new foreign key)` is better or I need to use `EAV` method?